# How to convert a date string like "2011-01-12T14:17:55.043Z" to a long like 1294841716?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, date

I need to convert a date in this string format:

"2011-01-12T14:17:55.043Z"

to a number like 1294841716 (which is the number of seconds [not milliseconds] since Jan. 1st, 1970).  Is there an easy way to do this parsing?

**Update:** Here is the code I've got so far:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-01-12T14:17:55.043Z";
NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.nnnZ"];
NSDate *parsed = [inFormat dateFromString:dateString];
long t = [parsed timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

But `t` comes back as 0 every time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get a `NSDate` then use `- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSince1970` to get the seconds since 1970.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2011-01-12T14:17:55.043Z"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
NSLog(@"1970: %f", [date timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSLog(@"sDate: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
[formatter release];
```

Comment: See my update: I don't seem to have the format string correct, or else I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: Try this and verify that it works. I am not expert on Date Format strings :). `[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];`

Comment: @MusiGenesis I added the default timeZone so it would not get parsed at local time since Z is the Zulu (UTC) timezone

Comment: you're hired! That actually explains a slight time discrepancy I was seeing.