# iOS NSDate returns (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have an issue with NSData. Im Trying to execute:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2014-08-14T23:55:55Z"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:dte]);
```

I get:

```
[4727:60b] (null)
```

How should I change date format to deal with this date?

Comment: Carefully look at your date string and then look at the format you specified. Notice the mismatch?

Comment: Updated letters T and Z like now. Still null...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a date string like "2011-01-12T14:17:55.043Z" to a long like 1294841716?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809216/how-to-convert-a-date-string-like-2011-01-12t141755-043z-to-a-long-like-1294)

Comment: I think not even similar. Except NSDate...

Comment: @JacobJones - Quite similar -- both have the "T" problem.

Comment: Yes, but question was not the same. Maybe problem caused by symbol ' can trigger different kinds of error. I think question should be duplicate, but not an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you want to use regular characters in a formatter, you need to quote them. Otherwise they can have a meaning (just like `y` or `M`). So the safe version to use here is

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Comment: The "Z" must not be quoted. Doing so will result in the wrong timezone.

Comment: I concluded that it would need to be quoted because in the string used in the question, `Z` is also a literal, not a timezone

Comment: The "Z" in the date string is the timezone, not a literal. It's the same as "UTC".

Comment: @rmaddy Oh I see. Sorry for that. Editing. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

instead of

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddZHH:mm:ssT"];
```